# Mongoid: respond_with newly-created embedded object raises UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

My controller action is supposed to `respond_with` a newly created `User::SmtpConfig` record, whose model is embedded inside a User record, but it misidentifies `user_id` for the new record and raises a `UrlGenerationError`.

**Error**

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError at /users/531604866465623cca000000/smtp_configs.json
>
> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users/smtp_configs",
>   :user_id=>#<User::SmtpConfig _id: 537a84af6465620a1f090000, uname:
>   "f", pwd: "a", host: "fdsaf", addr: "foo.bar.com", port: nil, tls:
>   nil, auth: nil>, :format=>nil, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

**Controller action**

```
respond_to :json

# This action is reached with the following URL path:
# /users/:user_id/smtp_configs/:id.json
def create
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @smtp = user.smtp_configs.create params
  @smtp.id      # => BSON::ObjectId('537a85286465620a1f0a0000')
  @smtp.user_id # => BSON::ObjectId('531604866465623cca000000')
  respond_with @smtp
end
```

Why is the controller trying to match any route at all? And why is `user_id` evaluating to the newly-created object itself?

Comment: This issue (attempt to find show method after create) often occurs when method create doesn't work correctly. In your case it seems to work fine though. Try `render json: @smtp`. Also you are using `params`, but in rails 4 it shouldn't work because of strong params (not sure)

Comment: `render json: @smtp` does indeed work, but it's less desirable because it doesn't include validation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, my solution was to supply a url as a `location` option in my `respond_with` call:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @smtp = @user.smtp_configs.create(resource_params)
  respond_with @smtp, location:polymorphic_url(@smtp, {user_id:@user, id:@smtp.id, format: :json})
end
```